# Right way to store sensitive credentials for web app

Tags: security, amazon-ec2, credentials

I have a Java web app running on EC2 under Tomcat (a WAR) that requires various sensitive configuration parameters - for example, the credentials associated with various other AWS services. I had been setting these as environment variables, but then discovered that running Tomcat as a service removes almost all environment variables. So currently I use a simple configuration file to store these values.

I don't believe this is a wise choice going forward, however, and would like to find an alternative. What is the right way to handle this kind of sensitive information?

Comment: I think this would be better suited for security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

IAM Roles are going to be your best friend here. The official docs [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/java-dg-roles.html) will point you in the right direction. There's also a post on the AWS security blog about it [here](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/TxC24FI9IDXTY1/Delegating-API-Access-to-AWS-Services-Using-IAM-Roles).

Comment: Thank you. This seems like a very good solution for me. I had briefly looked a IAM, but didn't appreciate that it could be used in this way.

Comment: Of course, if that answers you're question I'd appreciate it if you marked this as the answer.